# UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind called multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` attached on it. The problem is that `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is called every time when I scroll up the collection view. Is there any way to stop calling `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` more than one time?

Comment: its is called based on your sections count

Comment: Is there any Solution to stop calling more then one time ??

Comment: ha ha ha, then do like, set one section and add another things are row

Comment: what issue do you face with "calling more than one time"?

Comment: Why don't you like the fact it's called multiple times? Is it because of an issue with you view and a reuse not well managed?

Comment: Thank you Friends for your support...I came up with a solution that works like a charm...
I set a tag value for label for the first time when I create it and check whether the tag value is set or not in ‘viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind’ every time when I enter the loop. If it is set already then it will not redesign the label again and exit the loop. Updated the code change in comments. Hope this may help someone.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Its working perfectly, but I want to know its a correct way to do??

Answer (score 1):

The calling of `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` depends on the number of the sections and availability of Section header/footer. The `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is going to get called whenever a section that has a header or footer gets displayed in the view

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with a solution that works like a charm...
I set a tag value for label for the first time when I create it and check whether the tag value is set or not in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` every time when I enter the loop. If it is set already then it will not redesign the label again

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader])
    {
        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      if([reusableview viewWithTag:101] == nil)
      {
         [[reusableview viewWithTag:101] removeFromSuperview];
         pointsAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
         pointsAmountLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20);
         pointsAmountLabel.text = @"0";
         pointsAmountLabel.tag = 101;
         pointsAmountLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
         [reusableview addSubview:pointsAmountLabel];
     }
    return reusableview;
   }
return nil;
}
```